# AdonisJs - Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

In AdonisJS I created a controller with core command `node ace make:controller TodoController`, but I am getting this `Cannot find module`

Creating Controller:

```
node ace make:controller TodoController
```

Routes.ts:

```
import Route from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/Route";

Route.get("/", "homeController.index");

Route.group(() => {
  Route.get("/todo", "TodoController.index");
  Route.post("/todo", "TodoController.store");
  Route.patch("/todo/:id", "TodoController.update");
  Route.delete("/todo/:id", "TodoController.delete");
}).prefix("/api");
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!
Please provide the exact error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error when I upgraded to a newer adonis version.

After an upgrade you should run this command on your terminal (inside your project root)

```
node ace generate:manifest
```

This will index your ace commands and your problem should be solved.